# Multiple Activities in Android with 3 Activites

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating multiple `activities` in Android, this is my logcat error output.

**log.txt**

```
05-03 03:17:23.295: E/PhonePolicy(1854): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
05-03 03:17:37.044: W/dalvikvm(1854): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409db1f8)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jumoun.itemp/com.jumoun.itemp.Converter}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4427)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at com.jumoun.itemp.Converter.onCreate(Converter.java:41)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-03 03:17:37.044: E/AndroidRuntime(1854):     ... 11 more
05-03 03:17:38.704: I/Process(1854): Sending signal. PID: 1854 SIG: 9
```

This is my java file `Converter.java`
http://pastebin.com/VNNPy7D5

Thanks guys :)

Comment: It looks like one of your `Buttons` is actually an `ImageButton` in the xml. Is this right? Posting the xml would help also

Comment: Thanks uncle, you are correct, I just checked about it. :)

Comment: You are welcome. I also edited with a note about logcat. Once you understand how to read it, debugging is much easier. Don't forget to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I counted right this

```
ibHome3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ibHome3);
```

is causing your problem. You have it as an `ImageButton` in your xml but `Button` in your java declaration. Just change it to

```
ImageButton ibHome3;
```

**About Logcat**

Also, just a little advice on logcat. If you find the first line that says `Caused By` after `Fatal Exception` you can track down your problem easier. Here it is

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

this gives the exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
```

then find the first line after that which references your package. Here

```
at com.jumoun.itemp.Converter.onCreate(Converter.java:41)
```

this tells us the problem starts in `Converter.java` at line 41

Answer (score 1):

You have two buttons in your layout file, right? They looks to be defined as ImageButton in the XML file. In your Activity, you declare it as Button and try to convert with a cast to (Button). Change your type to ImageButton on your Activity file. It may solve your prolbem.

Answer (score 0):

On line 41, you have to cast your button to ImageButton and not Button :

```
ibHome3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibHome3);
```