# Asynctask crashes, can't find reason

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this Asynctask that is supposed to calculate the location of the user. The code inside the Asynctask works fine outside Asynctask, so I know that my error is at arranging the Asynctask, which I am very unfamiliar with.

Asynctask is ran by this line inside an onClick method:

```
new GetCurrentCity().execute();
```

And here is GetCurrentCity itself:

```
    private class GetCurrentCity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();


            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                if(addresses != null) {
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);

                    for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                   strReturnedAddress = (returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).toString();
        }
                }
            }

                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

        return strReturnedAddress;
    }
        protected void onPostExecute(String useless2){
            test.setText(strReturnedAddress);
        }
        }
```

As I have said I am a total newbie with different threads, so please excuse me if this is a very easy question.

Also, I am still severely struggling with parameters, so I feel like the problem is with them; yet, I have tried everything I could think of before coming here to ask.

Thank you in advance, and have a good day!

Edit: this is the current logcat

```
07-10 20:24:08.175: D/OpenGLRenderer(15827): Enabling debug mode 0
07-10 20:24:08.435: I/TextToSpeech(15827): Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.GoogleTTSService}
07-10 20:24:13.460: W/dalvikvm(15827): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41471930)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:197)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:197)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.location.LocationManager.wrapListener(LocationManager.java:820)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:833)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:430)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at com.example.realapptest1.MainActivity$GetCurrentCity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:306)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at com.example.realapptest1.MainActivity$GetCurrentCity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-10 20:24:13.465: E/AndroidRuntime(15827):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: post the error log for this error - your currently running this with no params

Comment: One thing that helped me understand AsyncTask was to make sure I put the `@Override` declaration on `doInBackground`, `onProgressUpdate`, and `onPostExecute` and watched what happened as I changed the types in the `extends` part. You'll see how they all relate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am still severely struggling with parameters, so I feel like the problem is with them

`params` taken by `doInBackground()` come from `execute()`. So whatever you put inside that method will be sent to `doInBackground()`. You can either put a `String` in there or `String` [vargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) or change your `doInBackground()` to not accept a `String`

```
     protected String doInBackground(Void... args)
```

then change your `AsyncTask` declaration to

```
 private class GetCurrentCity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
```

`doInBackground()` returns its value to `onPostExecute()` as you appear to be doing but you aren't using the value sent so there is no reason to `return` it.

`onProgressUpdate()` takes `params` from calling `publishProgress()` from `doInBackground()` to do something like update a `ProgressBar`.

Without seeing your logcat, its hard to say exactly what problem you are having but that is how you would send `params` to `AsyncTask`

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I have done what you have told me to do. The crash upon executing GetCurrentCity persists. Logcat only shows error in $GetCurrentCity/doInBackground().

Comment: I have just learned how to properly use logcats thanks to your last comment. I never thought that those numbers were lines. Problem was the locationManager had to be out of doInBackground. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. [Here is an answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346077/multiple-activities-in-android-with-3-activites/16346151#16346151) that explains how to read the logcat a little better